# How to stop repeated requests to install an app?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications, launcher

I'm getting the same message or rather, a notification, several times daily, a request to install an app (Zero Launcher, specifically) and it doesn't seem to stop. It's starting to feel like harassment. What can I do to stop that kind of thing for good? Just deleting the notification does nothing as the next one is always lurking around the corner. Thanks!
(My device is samsung galaxy s3)

Comment: Just uninstall the app that causes this notification. Long-press it and tap on `Application details´. Then uninstall it. Most of those applications are just full blown up with ads and are simply useless.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Thought of that. I have no idea which app is causing this. Any suggestions on how to find out?

Comment: As I have written: Long-press the notification and tap on `Application details` or similar.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. That's not what I got from your post, thought I needed to first know which app was causing it, not that I could work with the notification alone. (I fiddled with the notification as I had the notion of removing the app that's causing it but it got me nowhere, probably didn't do what you just described, though, and will gladly try!) Thank you again!

Comment: Are you rooted? If so, there is another way without deleting/uninstalling anything. I'll post if you have root.

Comment: Didn't have to wait too long for the next notification, i did what GiantTree suggested and it did the trick, so phew. :) Thank you for you offer though, HasH_Brown.